# How to attach different versions of same source file

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse Mars Release (4.5.0)

I have a few projects in the same namespace and two of them use different versions of the same library (percisely, spring 4.0.x and spring 4.2.x, update is not finished yet.)

Now when debugging a project that uses `Spring 4.2.1` eclipse erronously navigates me to sources of `Spring 4.0.x` (as in the picture below)

[image]

There is no instruction at the 629 line in `Spring 4.0.x`, but here is one in `Spring 4.2.1`.

***Question:*** How to tell eclise that I want to debug a project with the particular version of sources?

Comment: How are you "linking" the JARs? If you are using something like ivy, then each JAR has it's corresponding source downloaded (you just have to specify that you want them). If you are not using ivy, you should consider ;)